# Can you set the window in the app/scene delegate and still use storyboard?

Tags: swift

I have an app and I am trying to make a simple collectionView. The collectionView works fine if I run from the Main.storyboard using the `is initial View Controller`.

The problem is when I make my own window using this code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.rootViewController = ViewController()
    self.window = window
    return true
}
```

and

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.rootViewController = ViewController()
}
```

I get this error on my collectionView code:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to create your own UIWindow and still use storyboard?

P.S if you are wondering why I don't just use storyboard instead of making my own UIWIndow it's because I already have my app created completely programmatically and I just need to use storyboard this one time to make self sizing UICollectionViewCells. I couldn't figure out how to do it programmatically, but I have it figured out on storyboard.

Comment: are you trying to set root view controller from both appDelegate and scenedelegate ?

Comment: I think the crash is because you didn't set the `self.window` in `SceneDelegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your root view controller either from `SceneDelegate` or from `App Delegate` or from the `Storyboard`, you don't have to do it in all the places.

If you are just trying to initialize your `ViewController` from code you don't need any storyboard and the initializer you called  `ViewController()` does not instantiate a view controller from the storyboard. to know how you can instantiate a view controller associated with a storyboard please refer to this [link](https://cocoacasts.com/mastering-navigation-with-coordinators-instantiating-view-controllers-from-a-storyboard).

You can use any view controller as a root view controller it depends on you.

`isInitialViewController` sets that view controller as the root view controller of the window.

If you just want to use your `ViewController` as the root view controller which you already codded in the app delegate, now just delete the storyboard and its references from `info.plist` file then you are good to go.